# Ionic BLE Manufacturer specific Data

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy

Using `@ionic-native/ble` I'm able to scan and discover a BLE device which has manufacturer specific data.

According to the lib (https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central#ios-1) here is the way to get this data

```
const mfgData = new Uint8Array(device.advertising.kCBAdvDataManufacturerData);
console.log('Manufacturer Data: ', mfgData);

const hex = Buffer.from(mfgData).toString('hex');
console.log(hex);
```

The encode to hex result being `2604 0504 386 55c0b`

What I don't understand is the proper way to use this result to decode the manufacturer (company) id, which is supposed to be "0x0426"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following :

```
const toHexString = bytes =>
  bytes.reduce((str, byte) => str + byte.toString(16).padStart(2, '0'), '');

console.log(toHexString(new Uint8Array([0, 1, 2, 42, 100, 101, 102, 255])))
```

Comment: Thanks, but dosen't seem to change anything,  `Uint8Array(device.advertising.kCBAdvDataManufacturerData)` is `{"0":38,"1":4,"2":5,"3":4,"4":56,"5":101,"6":92,"7":11}`

Comment: Can you give me console of  device.advertising.kCBAdvDataManufacturerData

Comment: { CDVType = ArrayBuffer; data = "JgQFBDhlXAs="; }